# Rimworld: Material Selection

Tags: rimworld

In my current colony in Rimworld I have a lot of different materials. Unfortunately, when I want to buy a wall or something else, when I want to select the material, I can't see all available materials because they appear to be out of screen. In the top of the list I have all those shiny things like gold, silver jade and everything else and for example granite blocks (I have build all my things from granite blocks) are out of screen and I can't select them.

For walls I can work around that by selecting build clone (don't know if that's vanilla or mods) but for new items I can't select all my materials.

Is there a solution for that?

I play on 1920x1080 and lowest UI scale.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of right-clicking the Button on the bottom, like this:

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Where you are unable to see all Options, press the corresponding hot key on your Keyboard and have your Mouse e.g. in the middle of your Screen. This will bring up the list next to your Mouse Pointer:

[image: Screenshot of Hot Key]

[image: Screenshot of solution]

Comment: In all my hours in the game, never knew about that.

Comment: I just stumbled across this. Very nice tip. Thanks!